# Major Bug in Today's Chrome Update - 1000's of Web pages Display Improperly

Tags: google-chrome

Starting this afternoon, with the introduction of Chrome 31.0.1650.48, many web pages are displaying with random formatting errors.  I've confirmed this on both Mac and Windows machines running the most recent auto-updated Chrome release (31.0.1650.48).

This problem is affecting thousands of pages, and to immediately rule out our server generating different information, you can try this to reproduce the problem:

1. Visit this Google cache page with Chrome version specified above: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nt70v_rn5BwJ:alaskanmalamute.rescueme.org/Idaho+&cd=61&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us
2. Notice what dogs are displayed and where they are.
3. Reload the page several times and observer closely.
4. You will randomly see one dog listing in the middle of the page, then two dog listings, the dogs move around, the menus around the dogs move around.  Each time the page is reloaded Google is corrupting the source code in different ways, resulting in major formatting issues.  (NONE of this code is generated outside of Google's cache.)  All the pages on the www.RescueMe.Org have this problem, I'm using a cached page on Google's server in this article for an example since it proves it is not a server issue.

This sample page should remain the same every time, and be formatted correctly.  It isn't.

Google Chrome (when viewing source) seems to be making random changes to the page (Chrome is dropping < or > at random places in source code) causing major display formatting issues.

Can someone reproduce this?  Hopefully the folks at Google know about this issue, or someone here can escalate it with them?

Best wishes,

- Jeff

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a bug reporting site... Interesting though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not Google’s bug tracker. If you think you have discovered a bug (or simply want to know if anybody else has reported it already) – then head over to their bug tracker yourself!

Comment: I've tried posting at Google in their development areas, but I'm not sure if/when my reports might be seen.  This is currently breaking thousands of web pages on our websites, so I'm wondering if anyone here (from the programming side of things) might be able to determine what exactly is causing these pages to break. It seems like something must be triggering Chrome to behave erratically, but until I know what that is have no idea how to fix the thousands of web pages on our site that are now displaying horribly in Chrome on all platforms.  Thanks for your time and any feedback or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

can confirm - it seems to mostly be an issue with **iFrames**.
VisualForce iFrames in Salesforce break the entire layout.
Version 31.0.1650.48 on Mac, all addons removed.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into this issue, I've narrowed it down somewhat. Chrome/31.0.1650.48 will randomly scramble the placement of tables on a page if the following two things happen:

1) You start the page like this:  and do the reverse at the end:  (doesn't have to be face=arial, any font setting or even just  does the same thing).

2) Include some  tags within the page containing various tables.

3) Magic! (not good magic, though) Each time your tables will randomly move about the page.  Here's an example to try: http://server1c.rescueme.org/testb (Reload this page several times in in Chrome/31.0.1650.48 on Windows or Mac to see the tables jump around.)

THE SOLUTION: Start the page like this instead:  and do the reverse at the end:  (in other words, reverse placement of the center and font tags). Here's the "fixed" version of the page above with just those tags reversed: http://server1c.rescueme.org/testbfixed

While this is a Chrome bug, I feel this is worth keeping in Stack Overflow because this bug is breaking a lot of major sites, and programmers may want to know how to reprogram their HTML so those who have affected versions of Chrome won't have a confusing experience.

FYI... There are other ways to cause and solve this problem, but I'm trying to present here just the simplest method I found.